# Difference between "Push Notifications" and "In-App Notifications" in Facebook Analytics

Tags: facebook, push-notification, notifications

From the control panel at https://www.facebook.com/analytics/, I can see this:

[image]

What is the difference between "Push Notifications" and "In-App Notifications". I am new to push notifications from Facebook, but I have used Urban Airship and I would have thought that "Push Notifications" and "In-App Notifications" are synonyms. I know this may be a basic question about terminology more than a technical problem, but it would help to start by knowing the terminology used by Facebook Analytics. Thank you.

Edit: I was reading for example at https://github.com/facebook/FBNotifications the following sentence:

> Facebook In-App Notifications enables you to create rich and customizable in-app notifications and deliver them via push notifications

Does it mean that "push notification" is the delivery method/system, and "in-app notification" is the notification itself, such as its content, design, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/push-notifications/overview#app-events:

> Push Notifications
>
> Push notifications generally appear on the lock screen of a device, but they may also appear in a banner or other format, depending on the device. You can add a deep link to a push notification that opens up a specific experience in your app.
>
> In-App Notifications
>
> In-app notifications use rich media—such as photos, animated GIFs, emoji and more—to help you create engaging experiences that people receive directly in your app.

Find a more detailed explanation at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages. Using the terminology they incorporate in that link, "Notification message" would be what the Facebook documentation calls "Push Notification", and "Data message" would be what in the Facebook documents appears as "In-App Notifications".

Also, at the beginning of this video, the speaker clearly explains what "Push Notifications" and "In-App Notifications" are, even with images in the phone to visualize it. The video is from the official Facebook Developers account, so it is a reliable source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0K7AjHrK4TA.